# Is there a way i can use a text file to operate a program to display the occurrence of numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, text, io

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  fstream ticket ("numbers.txt");
  bool isCovered[99];
    int number;

  for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    isCovered[number] = false;
    // Read each number and mark its corresponding element covered
    ticket >> number;
  while (number != 0)
  {
    isCovered[number - 1] = true;
    ticket >> number;
  }

// Check if all covered
    bool allCovered = true; // Assumes all covered initially
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        if (!isCovered[i])
        {
            allCovered = false; //Finds one number not covered
            break;
        }

    return 0;
```

I know i may have confused you all with the last question i posted but this time i understand the concepts and have an even better question. How can i display the number of occurrences using a txt file in fstream while using C++? And how would i properly use my `for` and `if` loops for said problem, thanks?

Update: Got the numbers from the text file to display as well as numbers 1 - 99. But how do i code for the number of occurrences?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int i;
  // Open the text file in the system
  ifstream infile;
  infile.open("numbers.txt");

  if(infile.fail())
  {
    cout << "This file does not work";
  }
  else{
    string s;
    while(infile >> s){
      cout << s << endl;
    }
  }
  // Display all numbers 1 through 99
  for (i = 1; i < 99; i++){
    cout << i << endl;
  }



}
```

Comment: Note: `number` is uninitialized. That's bad if you're doing things like `isCovered[number]`.

Comment: I went and initialized the input `number`  in `fstream ticket ("numbers.txt");
  bool isCovered[99];
  int number;`

Comment: Unrelated: Prefer `while (ticket >> number && number != 0) { isCovered[number - 1] = true; }` Less repetition and also stops the loop if a number can't be read from the file.

Comment: Sort-of related: `bool isCovered[99];` could be `bool isCovered[99] = {};` This eliminates the need for the first `for` loop because it will initialize the whole array to false for you.

Comment: I changed the `while` loop, but what was the `for` loop to get the numbers to display in an easy column?

Comment: `int number;` doesn't give `number` a value. So it's not going to have any defined value it enter's the loop.

Comment: So i don't need `int number`?

Comment: You still need `int number;`. You just don't need it there. Since `for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)` iterates on `i`, you probably want to use `i` in the loop, not `number`.

Comment: please provide an example input and output, currently your code has no output at all, what should it print?

Comment: `80 65 56 43 10 01 10 34 56 43 12 56 76 06 08 34 43` This is from a txt file `numbers.txt` that i have trying to run in my program right now. I need it to print the following `Enter the integers between 1 and 99: [input here]` then display `X occurs X times` for the number of occurences. Without actually typing it in the system.